# How to generate hex values to dump into a Java simulated main memory, which will be working with a simulated cache?

Tags: java, caching, simulation

I am creating a cache simulation to show myself how it works and to prove to myself that I'm at least (hopefully) somewhat proficient in java and computing. So if I'm clearly wrong about something it would definitely help to hear outside input :)

My planned address size will be 12 bits (4 for tag, 5 for line, and 3 for the word). I'd like to randomly generate 32 lines of hex strings to be loaded into my simulated registers to represent a Main Memory. Then, at random I will select one of the lines in MM to be "used," hits/misses will be recorded, and if the line is nonexistent in cache it will be copied in. It's relatively simple but I plan to get deeper as I go.

I suppose I could have a text file full of lines I wrote myself, but if there's a way to randomly generate the data that's stored in memory that would be great.

Comment: Why simulating? Take `Unsafe` and play with actual memory :)

Comment: `java.util.Random`...? Unless I'm misunderstanding, you're just asking how to generate a block of random bytes which is pretty trivial to do. Maybe you are overcomplicating it by thinking the block of memory needs to mean something. (Does it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to randomly generate 32 lines of hex strings

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int bits = 12;      // bits in "byte"
int length = 10;    // number of "bytes" in string
int n = 32;         // number of strings

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      sb.append(Integer.toHexString(rnd.nextInt(1 << bits))).append(' ');
   }
   System.out.println(sb.toString());  // or write to file
}
```

Output:

```
d3b 2cc cf2 6ca c0c 8bb 47 e17 3ed 63e 
d48 396 5c9 69b 5bc 7f1 57e 356 8d5 9c3 
560 d45 10f c4d 2a5 a03 e08 13c bf 9b7 
...
```